# How to create an Internet facing Domain Controller Without VPN

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

I am extremely new to this.
I am trying to **create a domain controller** that could be **contacted via Internet**.

In clear words, I am trying to create a **Windows Server 2012 R2 domain controller with public IP**. I want my **windows 8.1 PC** to be able to **Ping and get domain joined** to that DC. I am looking for a scenario in which **VPN gateway is not required**. I am trying to achieve this for testing and educational purposes.(In my case My domain controller should be in Azure Environment, but I can make do without Azure too, since I am here to understand how things Actually work)

Since am extremely new to this, I am not sure how to do.

How many NICs will I need. 
How to assign VM a Public IP. 
How to make it accessible via Internet(If I try to Ping using cmd, it should give a reply). 
Since I am a newbie, I am looking to work from scratch.

Any help will be greatly appreciated?

Comment: You don't do this. You use a VPN. All of the software you need to use VPN is built into the OS. Why can you not use it?

Comment: If you're trying to understand how things actually work, a VPN is a critical piece of that. MS has Direct Access, which is based on IPSec, and is a seamless VPN. You can set that up if you'd like.

Answer (score 4):

Under no circumstances should a domain controller be facing the public internet. If you are doing this for educational purposes, then the education that you need is **don't do this**.

If you have Internet-only no-VPN machines that you want to manage, something like Azure AD join with enrollment into Intune for management is a far better option.

Comment: I don't understand why this is such a common answer and is advocated so much, yet nobody seems to know *why* this shouldn't be done.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Of course people know *why* it shouldn't be done. It's a service that was not designed to be exposed to the internet. It's very clear in Microsoft's documentation. The protocols and services that are used in Active Directory are not hardened for use across the public internet. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Yeah, I've read exactly that like 2 dozen times over the past 48 hours. But nobody every links to any actual documentation or can explain where the actual problem is. The internet is just another network. Why is it that the setup instantly becomes an issue just because it is "the internet". People say it's a security issue. How is it a security issue more so than with anything else that you put on the internet? You probably won't be able to explain it to me in this comment thread, but it would be nice to get an answer (other than "Don't") on the question posted here.

Comment: I can address a few items at least. First, look at [this list of ports and protocols in use](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772723(v=ws.10).aspx). You'll notice some protocols that are not designed for usage of the Internet, such as SMB. Additionally, you would need to publish your *internal* DNS zones externally. In many organizations, this is considered a significant security issue as it exposes hostnames, IP addresses, internal SRV and other resource records. You'll need to do *significant* DNS hardening to publish AD DS DNS on the Internet. Not a good idea.

Comment: Kerberos relies on client/server time being in sync. So you have to publish Windows time services publicly as well. There's no good way to scope it to domain-joined clients, so now your domain controllers are basically open NTP servers as well. There are a ton of other reasons too, those are just some examples that fit into a 500 character comment box on Server Fault :)